# JqueryUI Tabs, adding a tab to main tabs also adds tab to sub-tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a set of tabs where each tab container also has another set of tabs in it. When I dynamically add a tab to the top level tabs it also adds a tab to each of the second level tabs. I know why.. It appends a tab to the .ui-tabs-nav under the id of the top level tabs. When it does this it also appends each subsequent .ui-tabs-nav that falls under that same id div.  How would you make it add a tab only to the top level tabs and not the sub-tabs?

Here is the basic structure:

```
<div id="CustomerTabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1"><div class="TabDiv"><div class="TabDivName">Customer Search</div></div></a> </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2"><div class="TabDiv"><div class="TabDivName">Customer Profile</div></div></a> </li>
</ul>


<div id="tabs-1">


            <div id="CustomerSystemTabs1">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#CustTabs1-1"><div class="TabDiv"><div class="TabDivName">System 1</div></div></a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#CustTabs1-2"><div class="TabDiv"><div class="TabDivName">System 2</div></div></a> </li>
                </ul>


                <div id="CustTabs1-1">
                        <!-- Stuff Goes Here -->
                </div>

                <div id="CustTabs1-2">
                         <!-- Stuff Goes Here -->
                </div>


            </div> 

</div> 

    <div id="tabs-2">


            <div id="CustomerSystemTabs2">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#CustTabs2-1"><div class="TabDiv"><div class="TabDivName">System 1</div></div></a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#CustTabs2-2"><div class="TabDiv"><div class="TabDivName">System 2</div></div></a> </li>
                </ul>


                <div id="CustTabs2-1">
                        <!-- Stuff Goes Here -->
                </div>

                <div id="CustTabs2-2">
                        <!-- Stuff Goes Here -->
                </div>


            </div> 

</div>
```

This is how I am adding a tab:

```
        var tabTitle = $( "#tab_title" ),
        tabContent = $( "#tab_content" ),
        tabTemplate = '<li><a href="#{href}"><div class="TabDiv"><div class="TabDivName">#{label}</div><div class="TabDivClose"></div></div></a></li>',
        tabCounter = 2;

    var tabs = $( "#CustomerTabs" ).tabs();


    function AddCustomerTab(TabHTML,TabCaption){
        var label = TabCaption || "Tab " + tabCounter,
            id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
            li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),

            tabContentHtml = TabHTML || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";

        tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
        tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
        tabs.tabs( "refresh" );


        tabCounter++;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YnXH4/1/)

Your line of code

```
tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
```

selects all jQuery UI tabs and appends the li element (new tab) to all existing tabs.

In the fiddle I append the new tab to `$("#CustomerTabs ul:first")` which adds it only to the top level tabs.